# Проблема с кодировкой Java

Tags: java, кодировка, utf-8, кириллица

Столкнулся с проблемой чтения из файла: при выводе в консоль содержимого файла вместо кириллицы показывает такие символы[image: пример]

В Intelij IDEA везде (в файле, настройках) стоит кодировка UTF-8, текущая кодовая страница в консоли винды равна 866.

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: все сталкивались с этим. это известная проблема для windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте при открытии файла указать его кодировку:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("some_file.txt"), "utf-8"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Если java >= 1.7, то вместо "utf-8" я бы посоветовал использовать
StandardCharsets.UTF_8